# How does the SQL query look after parsing process

Tags: sql, parsing, oracle11g

Is it possible to know how a SQL query looks after parsing?

I would like to check a query after soft/hard parsing and how the final SELECT statement looks like.

Some statements are translated to more simply structure eg. ANY (query below) with equal operator might be EXISTS or NOT EXISTS with `<>`,`!=`

I looked for some view with query collection but I couldn't find.

```
CREATE TABLE PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (
 ID NUMBER
,NAME VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (5,'PAUL');
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (3,'JOHN');
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (2,'LEO');
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (1,'ADAM');
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (4,NULL);
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (NULL,'PETER');
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (NULL,'THOMAS');
INSERT INTO PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME (ID, NAME) VALUES (NULL,'DONALD');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME WHERE ID = ANY(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Oracle docs say that query after parsing looks:

```
SELECT ID,NAME
FROM   PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME 
WHERE  ID = 1 OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3 OR ID = 4 OR ID = 5;
```

Comment: what do you want to know, i don't understand it.

Comment: parsed SQL, my query looks like ```SELECT * FROM PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME WHERE ID = ANY(1,2,3,4,5);``` and the question is how it looks after parsing right before executing on server. That is only example of case and I'm interesting in how it works generally.

Comment: yes it seem correct `ANY` is going to be converted into `or`.

Comment: Exactly, we know it because we read oracle docs, but can we check how it looks in database actually ?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, if Oracle rewrites the query you will find an indication of that in the execution plan.

In your example, the plan output would look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name              | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                   |      5 |   200 |     3   (0)|
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME |      5 |   200 |     3   (0)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("ID"=1 OR "ID"=2 OR "ID"=3 OR "ID"=4 OR "ID"=5)
```

In the predicate information section, you can see that the condition `=ANY(..)` was rewritten to a series of `OR` conditions.

Similarly for the BETWEEN operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME 
WHERE id between 1 and 5;
```

will result in the following execution plan:

```
Plan hash value: 2712828397

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name              | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                   |      5 |   200 |     3   (0)|
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| PWY_TEST_ANY_SOME |      5 |   200 |     3   (0)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("ID">=1 AND "ID"<=5)
```

Again, the `BETWEEN` is rewritten to combination of `>=` and `<=`.

---

I don't think you will see every possible way something is rewritten, but still it's the first thing I would look at.